# Missing key when writing to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using the Java Kafka Streams API. I want to select a new key for a topic I'm consuming. The new key will be of a different type. When I use the console consumer to consume the topic with the new key, I can only see the values.

```
valueStream
    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue(value.getBook_id(), value))
    .peek((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("key: " + key); // prints key as expected
        System.out.println("value: " + value); // prints value as expected
    })
    .to("foobartopic", 
        Produced.with(Serdes.Integer(),bookValueIntSerde));
```

Result of consuming "foobartopic"
[image: actual result]

The expected result is the same but with a non blank key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your producer uses `Serdes.Integer` for key serialization, so to print key in user friendly format by `kafka-console-consumer` you have to set `--key-deserializer` to appropriate value. In your case it is `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer`.

`./kafka/bin//kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 --property print.key=true --from-beginning --topic foobartopic --key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer`